# Sum Array Specific Object In Java Spring

Tags: java, arrays, object, sum

How can i sum the spesific array in java here my respon json.

```
{
      "ResponA": {
        "SumA": "1000000"
      },
      "Respon B": [
      {
        "PaymentB": "Tax 2021",
        "SumB": "50"
      },
      {
        "PaymentB": "Tax 2020",
        "SumB": "20"
      }
      ],
    
      "ResponC": [
      {
        "PaymentC": "groceries 2020",
        "SumC": "10"
      },
      {
        "PaymentC": "groceries 2021",
        "SumC": "20"
      }
      ]
    }
```

i want to sum **"Respon A + All Array Respon B + All Array Respon C"**

and heres my code for getting the json respon.

```
String ResponA = respon.getBody().ResponA().SumA();
String ResponB = respon.getBody().ResponB().get(0).SumB();
String ResponC = respon.getBody().ResponC().get(0).SumC();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are min 2 things you need to do to get the answer there.
Things you need to know is

- How to iterate a list (for loops or streams in this case)
- How to convert String to Integer (Integer.parseInt(String))
- extra, when you define variables in Java use **camelCase**, as this is the standard.

using above mentioned things. You should be able to calculate the sum. Following is kind of a pseudo code for your problem.

```
int total = 0;
total = convert responA string to int(Integer.parseInt(responA)) + total;
//write a for each loop to calculate ResponB values
for (ResponB res: respon.getBody().ResponB()){
   total = total + Integer.parseInt(res.sumB());
}
//write another for each loop to calculate ResponC values
for each (ResponC res: respon.getBody().ResponC()){
   total = total + Integer.parseInt(res.sumC());
}
//now you have. the total
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: You can improve your json itself . eg. Use int values for SumA, SumB and SumC then you won't need to do all those Integer.parseInt() stuff. Anyway I just gave an answer to your current problem only.